# Locale language in lightning community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, napili, language, lightning-community, locale

In a lightning component, I am currently using `$Locale.language` to get the users language locale, however, I am also considering to use `navigator.language`

> The **NavigatorLanguage.language** read-only property returns a string
>   representing the preferred language of the user, usually the language
>   of the browser UI.
>
> **VS**
>
> $Locale The **$Locale** global value provider returns information
>   about the current user’s preferred locale. These attributes are based
>   on Java’s Calendar, Locale and TimeZone classes.

I have a situation where in a lightning community, I have setup multilingual support and have articles in different languages. therefore, I am trying to rely on either the `$Locale` global value provider or `navigator.language` to filter on the users preferred language.

while using `navigator.language` I effectively get the browsers language accurately (so far), but for some reason, `$Locale.language` always returns `'es'`

I tested using Chrome in Incognito mode and have the same behavior:

> `$Locale.language`   -> 'es'
>
> `navigator.language` -> ok (es, fr, en...)

I am using an unauthenticated Guest user in the community, just to make sure that I don't get the users preferred language set in Salesforce.

(just realized what might be causing this, will test and update the post, or answer myself)

Comment: I presume `$Locale.language` reflects the setting on the server-side User object and so is always the same whatever locale is set on the device the user logs in from whereas `navigator.language` reflects the locale set on the device. Pros and cons for both mechanisms but its the former that is the norm for SF.

Comment: Yes, it is what I was suspecting. Last night I figured out where and how to change the $Locale.language value.

Comment: Hey glls, How do you use navigator.locale/ navigator.language in apex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Locale.language reflects the site language which can be changed or set under the Site studio.com configuration:

[image]

At first I thought it might be based on the assigned user to the guest profile for the community, but after changing it, I confirmed this was not the case.